# Is Spark's "Hadoop Free" distribution completely compatible with all Hadoop versions?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

There is distribution of Spark that doesn't bundle hadoop libraries inside. It requires setting SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH variable that points to provided hadoop libraries.

Apart from this, there is also "Building Spark" that states about incompatibility between different versions of hdfs:

> Because HDFS is not protocol-compatible across versions, if you want
>   to read from HDFS, you’ll need to build Spark against the specific
>   HDFS version in your environment. You can do this through the
>   hadoop.version property. If unset, Spark will build against Hadoop
>   2.2.0 by default. Note that certain build profiles are required for particular Hadoop versions

Do I understand it right that this is only referred to Spark distributions bundling specific version of hadoop? And "Hadoop Free" can run on any hadoop version as soon as runtime-available jars have classes and methods that Spark uses in source code? So I can safely compile Spark with hadoop-client 2.6 and run in on Hadoop 2.7+?